# Debug Android Media Box App in Laptop

Tags: android, debugging, ionic-framework, usb, android-tv

I am developing an Android App using Ionic Framework. The app works fine in Mobile Phone but when I install it in my Android Media Box (X93 Mini), it shows blank screen after Splash Screen. 
To see what's wrong, I am trying to connect the Media Box to my Laptop using USB 3.0 cable, but nothing happens.

After research I came to know that my laptop has USB 3.0 port, whereas the Media Box has USB 2.0 port and doesn't support USB 3.0

Is there anything I can do to make it work?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there is an issue with Debugging with USB in Android Media Boxes (Android TV). I have found another way which is super simple and doesn't required any wire/cable.

1- Make sure your laptop and Media Box are on the same Wi-fi network.

2- Find your Media Box IP Address (in Network Settings).

3- Open Command Prompt in your Laptop and type `adb connect [IP_ADDRESS]:5555`.

4- If everything goes well, the output will be like `connected to [IP_ADDRESS]`.

5- Your Laptop and Media Box is connected and you can debug your app :)

Cheers! :D